# DataGridView CausesValidation does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to turn all kind of validation off from `DataGridView` but setting `DataGridview.CausesValidation=false` does not work, it always throw exception "input data not recognized"

`DataGridView` is bound to a DataTable which has column of DateTime data type but I would like to add enter some custom date formats which are not valid for some cultures e.g. 11.12.2013, 10-12-2013, 11/11/2013.

Since, I need sorting on these columns hence, I would like to keep them datetime instead string/varchar

Its a C# WinForm application.

Answer (score 0):

By default no validation is happening. Its not `DataGridView` that validates data, but underlying type, in your case `DateTime`.

If you really want to keep datetime column of type `DateTime` you should convert all input data to one single format chosen by you. You can still show (internally they will remain in default culture) them differently by converting to specific culture in runtime (although it requires additional code and care if this data is not read-only)

Here is code snippet for what I mean - you store data as `DateTime` in culture A (defined by `Thread` or yourself) and show it as string converted to specific Culture B.

When user tries to enter Date in any format it will be correctly parsed and saved in culture B (however user will see it in that specific culture A).

The problem here - if client enters date in any other culture than B after save it will be visually converted to B.

This is property of List which populates `DataGridView`

```
        private DateTime _dt1; 
        public string dt1 { 
            get 
            {
                return _dt1.ToString(new CultureInfo("nl-NL"));
            } 
            set
            {
                _dt1 = DateTime.Parse(value);
            }
        }
```

Regarding sorting problem - it is relatively easy to implement custom sort that will compare not displayed `strings` but their underlying `DateTime` properties

Comment: Different columns may have different date formats that means I cannot convert them all to a common one, however each column will have same format for all rows. Provided that I need to persist display format to what user entered.

Comment: `I need to persist display format to what user entered` by populating predefined DateTime column with that culture? If so, you need to hide all columns except 1 for client to fill. If this is the case check my edited answer